# JQuery DataTable prevent server calls in client mode

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use DataTable in client side mode. I mean I want to make all data loading, row adding and deleting processes done in client (web browser).

I'm using following code to initialize DataTable and it loads table rows correnctly from complex class object (PriceItems). But during in initialize process it makes http post request to server. 
Why? 
How can I prevent this?

```
var pricesTable = $('#pricesTable').DataTable({
     data: viewModel.product.PriceItems,
     columns: [{
         data: 'Id',
         visible: false
     }, {
         data: 'Name'
     }, {
         data: 'Value'
     }, {
         data: 'CurrencySymbol'
     }, {
         data: 'UnitName'
     }],

     sort: false,
     processing: false,
     serverSide: false,
     deferLoading: 0,
     info: false,
     filter: false,
     lengthChange: false,

     fnInitComplete: function (oSettings, json) {
         $('#pricesTable tbody tr:eq(0)').click();
     }

 });
```

**EDIT-1:** If I use (serverSide: true) DataTable stops calling mvc controller!
**EDIT-2:** Data model populated at server side with the following code.

```
var viewModel = new ProductFormViewModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
```

Comment: `viewModel.product.PriceItems` fetching the data ...

Comment: Please look at EDIT 2

Comment: Has 'Model' actually been populated when you pass it to the view? Just wondering if your query uses deferred execution and is trying to enumerate the result set at the point of datatable initialisation.

Comment: Model populated in edit ([HttpGet]) action of controller and controller pass it to the view. Part of view is    $(document).ready(function () {
 var viewModel = new ProductFormViewModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
}

Answer (score 0):

Removed data attribute from the initialization of datatable because it send request to that url, try following code .

```
var pricesTable = $('#pricesTable').DataTable({
     columns: [{
         data: 'Id',
         visible: false
     }, {
         data: 'Name'
     }, {
         data: 'Value'
     }, {
         data: 'CurrencySymbol'
     }, {
         data: 'UnitName'
     }],

     sort: false,
     processing: false,
     serverSide: false,
     deferLoading: 0,
     info: false,
     filter: false,
     lengthChange: false,

     fnInitComplete: function (oSettings, json) {
         $('#pricesTable tbody tr:eq(0)').click();
     }

 });
```

Comment: How will the datatable be populated?

Comment: I've tried removing data attribute from initialization code but nothings changed. It persistently calling controller get action.

Comment: Then please check again that controller request initiated from where?

Comment: If I set serverSide property to true (in my case it should be false) datatable  works as expected and never call any http post action method. But this time it calls to controller on adding rows at client :) Really interesting...

Comment: Unfortunately I have no solution yet

Comment: can you give me url of that page?

Comment: [Test Page](http://54.93.111.122/portal/Home/About) Click on about link.There is a datatables grid that even data property is not linked to anything.